# ORA-38301 when saving blobs

Tags: ruby, oracle, blob, sequel, oci8

After saving between 1,000-4,000 BLOBs I get ORA-38301, "can not perform DDL/DML over objects in Recycle Bin". If I do "purge recyclebin" and restart my program, it often continues saving BLOBs successfully.

How can I avoid triggering ORA-38301 when saving BLOBs? They are JPEG images about 30k in size.

My function for saving a blob (Ruby using Sequel):

```
def save_oracle_blob(database, table, id_column, id_value, blob_column, blob_value)
    # Lock the value using a transaction:
    database.transaction do
        database.execute("UPDATE #{table} SET #{blob_column}=EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE #{id_column}='#{id_value}'")
        lob = database.execute("SELECT #{blob_column} FROM #{table} WHERE #{id_column}='#{id_value}' FOR UPDATE").fetch[0]
        lob.write(blob_value)
        lob.flush
        lob.close
    end
end
```

The debug log showing transactions and SQL statements, at the time of the error:

```
Transaction.begin
UPDATE profile_photos SET photo=EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE id='22479'
SELECT photo FROM profile_photos WHERE id='22479' FOR UPDATE
Transaction.rollback
lob.c:812:in oci8lib_210.so: OCIError: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 (Sequel::DatabaseError)
ORA-38301: can not perform DDL/DML over objects in Recycle Bin
```

Again, this is successful 99.9% of the time, but it consistently fails after saving 1-4 thousand BLOBs.

Comment: Your oracle version is?

Comment: What is in the recycle bin before you purge it?  Objects get into the recycle bin when they are dropped.  Nothing in the code you posted should drop anything.

Comment: My Oracle version:
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
    CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: When I query the recyclebin after this error, it always appears to be empty. I executed "purge recyclebin" in order to recover, but it might not be accomplishing anything.

Comment: How often are you committing changes?

Comment: The recycle bin is empty before and after I attempt to purge it.

Comment: I'm committing changes 1) After inserting a new row and 2) After after writing the content into the blob.

Comment: I got a ORA-38301 when my SYSTEM tablespace was almost full. I extended the related datafile and the problem was gone. (Oracle db 11.2.0.4)

Comment: I also got this error recently, when the tablespace was not full, but the user had quota on it. So in effect, it was "out of space". I'm not sure why this situation triggers the ORA-38301 error. I recovered by doing a PURGE RECYCLEBIN.